# $metadata 404 (Not Found)

Tags: asp.net, odata, sapui5

I have built an OData v3 endpoint that will be consumed by OpenUI5. I can now access http://localhost:27322/odata/Products/ on the browser with results, but when I consume this in OpenUI5 like this:

```
var oModel = new
    sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("http://localhost:27322/odata/Products/", false);
```

I get an error:

> GET http://localhost:53954/odata/$metadata 404 (Not Found)

I want to make a model of product lists. Am I wrong to call http://localhost:53954/odata/Products/$metadata instead of http://localhost:53954/odata/$metadata?

Answer (score 0):

If you app works on localhost, but fails on the cloud, your problem may be in wrongly defined destination to the OData service.

I had the same issue until the destination to the northwind OData service were defined properly.

Comment: my problem is on the localhost, i can access the endpoint using browser(chrome), but not on a local web app with SAPUI

Comment: @rajeemcariazo Do you use LocalProxyServlet when you run your app locally?